# Internet Explorer 9 doesn't send data to the database in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, internet-explorer, express

I have an express website that has a form in it. That form allows us to send users information data to the database (mysql). It came to my attention that the submit functionality doesn't send any data to the database when we use Internet Explorer. The other browsers work perfectly fine. But IE sends nothing to the database. When the submit has been clicked with IE, the form sends us to the confirmation page indication submission is successful. But nothing inside the database. The code that I use is below. This is the admission.js router file.

```
router.post('/add-application', function (req, res) {
var first_name = req.body.first_name;
var middle_name= req.body.middle_name;
var last_name = req.body.last_name;

//check errors
req.checkBody('first_name', 'First name is required').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
    res.render('/error', {
        errors:errors,
        first_name : first_name,
        middle_name :  middle_name,
        last_name : last_name          
    });
} else {
    var applications = {
       first_name : first_name,
        middle_name :  middle_name,
        last_name : last_name
    };
}

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO applications SET ?', applications, function (err, result) {
    console.log('Error:' + err);
    console.log('Success: ' + result);
});

req.flash('success_msg', 'Application Inserted!');
res.redirect('/');
});
```

And I have the following scripts for IE on the header as well:

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the form:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2>Register</h2>
    <form class="form-register" method="post" action="/admission/add-application">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Information</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the first name" required><br />

                    <label>Middle Name</label>
                    <input name="middle_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the middle name" ><br />

                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the last name" required ><br />

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input style="width:25%" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 9 || < doesn't support major components. Websockets and submitting form functionalities are just two of them. So the solution is very simple. DO NOT use IE.